# Java Scanner to read both Unix and Windows Line feed

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am reading a text file using Java `Scanner`. File can either end with `CRLF` or `LF` character (But not a mix of both). I am using the below code snippet:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)){
    scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("(\\n) | (\\r\\n)"));
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

However, its not working the way I am expecting it to. Its unable to read line by line, instead printing the entire file content. If I use either `LF` or `CRLF`, its working fine.

What am I doing wrong? How can I support both Line feed characters?

Comment: Could you attach some good/bad input/output?

Comment: @Rcordoval You can mimic it with any sample file having either LF or CRLF line ending character in it.

Comment: Why don't you get it from system properties? scanner.useDelimiter
       (System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Answer (score 0):

I think the extra spaces around your `|` are the problem. Have you tried without them?

As far as I can see you could also simplify your regex: `\n|\r\n` or `\r?\n`

Comment: Except you have to escape \ so you have `\\r?\\n`